# Is there a way to use AWTUtilities on JRuby?

Tags: java, jruby, awtutilities

I am trying to give a window in my desk app transparency. I've come across the AWTUtilities method, setWindowOpacity(), but I haven't been able to use it on my project. The line   `import com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities` 
does not seem to work.

Is there a way to use AWTUtilities on JRuby?

I have very little JRuby knowledge and even less Java. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like any other Java class in JRuby, if you are using Sun JDK:

```
java_import 'com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities'
```

Here is an example:

```
require 'java'

java_import 'javax.swing.JFrame'
java_import 'javax.swing.JButton'
java_import 'com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities'

f = JFrame.new
f.add JButton.new('test')
f.title = 'title'
f.set_size(200,200)

AWTUtilities.set_window_opacity(f, 0.75)
f.visible = true
```

Comment: Thank you Sébastien, but when I try to run the script I get an error 'cannot load Java class com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities (NameError)'.

I checked and I have installed sun-java6-jdk.

Comment: @slvdrog: what does `java -version` give?

Comment: ébastien: this, 

This: java version "1.6.0_20" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.7) (6b20-1.9.7-0ubuntu1) OpenJDK Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: I had JRuby 1.5 installed, updated to 1.6 and still getting the same error. Any advise?